# Removing class from two elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I have a weird (one more time) issue on my animation.

In a nutshell, I have a picture, when I clicked on it, two div appears, and there is a close button to remove those divs. But when I click on that button, there is only one div who dissapears.

The two new divs have got a debug class and I normally remove it when I clicked on the button

```
$('#gallery').on('click', 'li', function(e) {

        // To display the animations with position
        var $this = $(this),
            dataItem = $this.data('item');

        // Left animation
        if ( dataItem == 1 ) {
            console.log( $this );

            $this
                .addClass('active')
                .find('.info-texte')
                    .removeClass('hidden')
                    .addClass('debug');

            // When animation is ended add the second part
            $this.find('.debug').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function() {
                $this.find('.info-btn')
                    .removeClass('hidden')
                    .addClass('debug');
            });
        }

        // Supprime le href event
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.btn-close').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this
            .parents()
            .eq(3)
                .removeClass('active')
                .find('.info-texte, .info-btn')
                    .removeClass('debug')
                    .addClass('hidden');
    });
```

You can see in action right here : http://www.jeremybarbet.com/effect/bug.html

Comment: I don't see a close button. Can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: it's because your this.parents().eq(3) doesn't target the correct div - if you click your button, the active class still remains on what I guess you are targeting to remove that class from

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester There is an online version, the close button appears after clicking on the picture.

Comment: @Pete However, when I clicked on the close button, the right div disappears and the active class is remove too, there is only the .info-texte who is always here.

Comment: on your example above if you inspect the element - the li, the active class remains after you have clicked the button - why not try using `.parents('li.active')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments, your  `$this.parents().eq(3)` is targeting the wrong element

if you change this to `$this.parents('li.active')`

both of your divs should dissapear:

http://jsfiddle.net/TDsCT/

**EDIT**

After closer inspection it is because of your click:

`$('#gallery').on('click', 'li'`

this is also fired when you click on the button as the button is inside your `#gallery li`.  I have changed your code so you click on the image instead to open and then click on your button to close:

http://jsfiddle.net/TDsCT/5/

Comment: I just take the part of your code, and add to the rest of the code. I think there is a conflict between the part of code who add the class of the animation, and the part of the code who remove this animation and hide these two divs. http://jsfiddle.net/TDsCT/1/

Comment: Ok it works perfectly, thanks a lot, but it was a weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the expression $this.parents().eq(3) isn't evaluating to your desired result -- the two divs on the left. Perhaps try a different set of DOM traversal methods? (e.g. $this.parents().eq(2).prev() and $this.parents().eq(2), though this would be sort of a kludge)

Comment: Hum, I tried lot of methods but nothing works.

EDIT : I make some changes on the script, and when I change the css background, it is well change on the first div, but when I tried to remove a class, and add another one, nothing appears.

http://www.jeremybarbet.com/effect/bug.html